# Check if input contains 8 chars min, 1 digit and 1 letter minimum

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Here's what I tried...
It works if I only check if the value of the input is lesser than 8, but doesn't work to check if it contains at least 1 letter and 1 digit. What am I doing wrong ? =/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var jVal = {
    'passWord' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="nameInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var nameInfo = $('#nameInfo');
        var ele = $('#password');
        var pos = ele.offset();
        ra = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        re = /^[0-9]+$/;

        nameInfo.css({
            top: pos.top - 3,
            left: pos.left + ele.width() + 15
        });

        if (ele.val().length < 8 & re.test(ele.value) & ra.test(ele.value)) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            nameInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; too short').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        }

        else {
            nameInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    }

}
$('#password').change(jVal.passWord);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single regex to do everything:

```
/^(?=.*\d.*)(?=.*[a-z].*)\w{8,}$/i
```

The first two pieces check for both a digit, and an a-z char in the whole string, and then the last piece ensures it's at least 8 characters. You could change the last `\w` to `.` to allow special chars if so desired.

Answer (score 6):

`ra` checks if the password is made ENTIRELY of letters. `re` checks if the password is made ENTIRELY of numbers. They are mutually exclusive and therefore cannot both be true.

Instead, use `ra = /[a-z]/i; re = /[0-9]/;`.

EDIT: Also, since you're using jQuery, you should be testing on `ele.val()`, not `ele.value`.